# php json_encode missing [] on sub array

Tags: php, json

I'm new to the json_encode php world. I'm running 7.3.31. I am trying to get a json output that looks like:

I need [] around the srcList and freqList data.

```
{
  "freq": 851175000,
  "start_time": 1683137391,
  "emergency": 0,
  "encrypted": 0,
  "call_length": 1.6,
  "talkgroup": 14301,
  "talkgroup_tag": "NorBruns EMS Dsp",
  "talkgroup_description": "EMS Dispatch",
  "talkgroup_group_tag": "EMS Dispatch",
  "talkgroup_group": "North Brunswick",
  "audio_type": "digital tdma",
  "freqList": {
    "freq": 851175000,
    "time": 1683137391,
    "pos": 0,
    "len": 1.6,
    "error_count": 0,
    "spike_count": 0
  },
  "srcList": {
    "src": 1214950,
    "time": 1683137391,
    "pos": 0,
    "emergency": 0,
    "signal_system": "",
    "tag": ""
  }
}
```

The freqList and srcList need the [] around the array but I've try array() etc with no luck.

My php array looks like:

```
$my_array= [
     'freq' => $freq3,
     'start_time' => $ts,
     'emergency' => 0,
     'encrypted' => 0,
     'call_length' => $callDuration,
     'talkgroup' => $tg,
     'talkgroup_tag' => $AlphaTag,
     'talkgroup_description' => $Description,
     'talkgroup_group_tag' => $Tag,
     'talkgroup_group' => $Category,
     'audio_type' => "digital tdma",
     'freqList' => [
          'freq' => $freq3,
          'time' => $ts,
          'pos' => 0,
          'len' => $callDuration,
          'error_count' => 0,
          'spike_count' => 0
     ],
     'srcList' => [
          'src' => $src,
          'time' => $ts,
          'pos' => 0,
          'emergency' => 0,
          'signal_system' => "",
          'tag' => ""
     ]
];
$input2 = json_encode($my_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In json they are objects and not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the indexed array be a sole member of an numerically-indexed array:

```php
$my_array = [
    'freq' => $freq3,
    'start_time' => $ts,
    'emergency' => 0,
    'encrypted' => 0,
    'call_length' => $callDuration,
    'talkgroup' => $tg,
    'talkgroup_tag' => $AlphaTag,
    'talkgroup_description' => $Description,
    'talkgroup_group_tag' => $Tag,
    'talkgroup_group' => $Category,
    'audio_type' => "digital tdma",
    'freqList' => [
        [
            'freq' => $freq3,
            'time' => $ts,
            'pos' => 0,
            'len' => $callDuration,
            'error_count' => 0,
            'spike_count' => 0
        ],
    ],
    'srcList' => [
        [
            'src' => $src,
            'time' => $ts,
            'pos' => 0,
            'emergency' => 0,
            'signal_system' => "",
            'tag' => ""
        ],
    ],
];
$input2 = json_encode($my_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

You'll get:

```json
{
  "freq": 851175000,
  "start_time": 1683137391,
  "emergency": 0,
  "encrypted": 0,
  "call_length": 1.6,
  "talkgroup": 14301,
  "talkgroup_tag": "NorBruns EMS Dsp",
  "talkgroup_description": "EMS Dispatch",
  "talkgroup_group_tag": "EMS Dispatch",
  "talkgroup_group": "North Brunswick",
  "audio_type": "digital tdma",
  "freqList": [
    {
      "freq": 851175000,
      "time": 1683137391,
      "pos": 0,
      "len": 1.6,
      "error_count": 0,
      "spike_count": 0
    }
  ],
  "srcList": [
    {
      "src": 1214950,
      "time": 1683137391,
      "pos": 0,
      "emergency": 0,
      "signal_system": "",
      "tag": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: that give me:

```
"freqList": {
        "0": {
            "freq": 853387500,
            "time": 1683139144,
            "pos": 0,
            "len": 0.68,
            "error_count": 0,
            "spike_count": 0
        }
    },
```

Comment: Which is exactly what `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` does.